# AngularJS: Make ng-model available outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

In my AngularJS app, I am looping through an array object and send the value to a radio input as value. The overall idea is that the user selects a radio box and the value with be back part of $routeParams. **Unfortunately, the variable `{{ modelSelected }}` does not seemed to be available outside of the ng-repeat. Why?** The first  never shows the variable `{{ modelSelected }}`.

Does AngularJS creates a ScopeChild within the ng-repeat?

[Link to my jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/neurix/v0ocLmrf/)

```
<html ng-app>
    <body ng-init="models = [{name:'Sam'},{name:'Harry'},{name:'Sally'}]">
        <h3> Selected {{ modelSelected }} shown outside paragraph</h3>

        <div ng-repeat="model in models">
            <p>{{ model.name }} -
                <input ng-model="modelSelected" type="radio" name="patient" value="{{ model.name }}" required>
            </p>
             <h3> Selected {{ modelSelected }} shown inside paragraph</h3>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When dealing with primitives or using bindings generally try to prefer using a `.` in the model property that is being bound. So that when a child scope is created prototypical inheritance will carry down the properties (which are reference types) down to the children. (using `$parent` almost always is considered as a hack). In your case the property `modelSelected` is a primitive (even if it is present on the parent scope) and `ng-repeat` creates a child scope which does not finds this property (since inheritance does not carry it down even if it were present) and creates a new property on its scope, so the changes made to that are not seen to the outer scope.

Initialize a property on the scope as an object, `selection={}` in your scope (in your example it would be the outerscope). And bind the model as `ng-model="selection.modelSelected`

Ex:-

```
<body ng-init="models = [{name:'Sam'},{name:'Harry'},{name:'Sally'}]; selection={}">
        <h3> Selected {{ selection.modelSelected }} shown outside paragraph</h3>

        <div ng-repeat="model in models">
            <p>{{ model.name }} -
                <input ng-model="selection.modelSelected" type="radio" name="patient" value="{{ model.name }}" required>
            </p>
             <h3> Selected {{ selection.modelSelected }} shown inside paragraph</h3>

        </div>
 </body>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TGno9m?p=preview)**

Read: [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: I would prefer this over use of `$parent`.  This is better practice and you will not run into having to do `$parent.$parent.$parent` to get to a variable in a scope you want.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne I can't agree more, apart from that child needs to have the knowledge of the existence of parent itself, which is not a good thing.

Comment: I like the way with the scope variable too. Already implemented and it works great. Thank you for the explanation. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It does create a new scope that inherits the parent scope. Use $parent.modelSelected to access the parent scope's variable.

```
<body ng-init="models = [{name:'Sam'},{name:'Harry'},{name:'Sally'}]">
     <h3> Selected {{ modelSelected }} shown outside paragraph</h3>

    <div ng-repeat="model in models">
        <p>{{ model.name }} -
            <input ng-model="$parent.modelSelected" type="radio" name="patient" value="{{ model.name }}" required>
        </p>
         <h3> Selected {{ modelSelected }} shown inside paragraph</h3>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reading the different answers, I think I prefer @PSL reply with the scope variable. I am afraid that I would start chaining the $parent variables.

Comment: Sure. np. I was initially going to add another variable in the parent scope, but for brevity's sake just pointed you to $parent. Obviously it is not good to use $parent everywhere, but in this case didn't seem   unreasonable. Good explanation by @PSL though.

Answer (score 1):

The `{{modelSelected}}` would not be available outside the `ng-repeat` because of how scope works in AngularJS (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

> Scopes are arranged in hierarchical structure which mimic the DOM structure of the application

So since the `<h3>` element you are trying to access the `{{modelSelected}}` object from is outside the scope of the iterator, the object is not available.

Comment: There are several ways that this can be done.  You aren't really answering the question, just restating the problem.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thank you for the link to the scope documentation.